# Exception in callback AsyncIOScheduler.wakeup

Tags: python, pyqt, python-asyncio

Working with a PyQt application that uses the AsyncioScheduler which is giving me fits. The application is controlling a Kasa SmartStrip, using the Kasa api which uses async functions. The code listed below has a fake Kasa implementation but the results are the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys
import time
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from asyncqt import QEventLoop, asyncSlot
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
    
# Fake Kasa SmartStrip class.
# turn_on and turn_off are async functions, so use asyncio.sleep
# to implement an async function
class SmartStrip:
   def __init__(self, address):
      self.address = address
            
      async def update(self):
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
      return ('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())
            
      async def turn_on(self, child):
         await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
      async def turn_off(self, child):
         await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
# Allow control (turn_on/turn_off) the individual sockets (upper/lower)
# in the wall plug
# sched_on/sched_off allows to set an on/off time.
class MyPlug(SmartStrip):
   def __init__(self, ip_address):
      super().__init__(ip_address)
             
      async def initialize(self, child):
         coroutine = self.update()
         result = await coroutine
         print(result)
            
      async def turn_on(self, child):
         coroutine = self.initialize(child)
         result = await coroutine
            
      async def turn_off(self, child):
         coroutine = self.initialize(child)
         result = await coroutine
            
      async def sched_on(self, sched):
         sched.add_job(MyPlug.turn_on, 'interval', seconds=3, args=[self, 0])
    
      async def sched_off(self, sched):
         sched.add_job(MyPlug.turn_off, 'interval', seconds=7, args=[self, 0])
    
# A QDialog which contains buttons to (turn on/ turn off) the (upper or
# lower) sockets. Also allows scheduling to turn on/off.
class Form(QDialog):
   loop = None
   scheduler = None
        
   def __init__(self, loop=None):
      super(Form, self).__init__()
          
      self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    
      self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
      scheduler = self.scheduler
           
      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      self.setLayout(layout)
      self.uon_name   = "Upper On"
      self.uoff_name  = "Upper Off"
      self.lon_name   = "Lower On"
      self.loff_name  = "Lower Off"
      self.sched_name = "Schedule"
      self.quit_name  = "Quit"
          
      # Upper On
      self.up_on = QPushButton("Upper On")
      self.up_on.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.up_on))
    
      # Upper Off
      self.up_off = QPushButton("Upper Off")
      self.up_off.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.up_off))
    
      # Lower On
      self.lo_on = QPushButton("Lower On")
      self.lo_on.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.lo_on))
    
      # Lower Off
      self.lo_off = QPushButton("Lower Off")
      self.lo_off.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.lo_off))
    
      # Schedule
      self.sched = QPushButton("Schedule")
      self.sched.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.sched))
    
      #Quit
      self.quit = QPushButton(self.quit_name)
      self.quit.clicked.connect(lambda:self.quit_app())
          
      layout.addWidget(self.up_on)
      layout.addWidget(self.up_off)
      layout.addWidget(self.lo_on)
      layout.addWidget(self.lo_off)
      layout.addWidget(self.sched)
      layout.addWidget(self.quit)
          
      self.setWindowTitle("Outlet Demo")
      self.mp = MyPlug("10.0.0.31")
          
      @asyncSlot()
      async def whichbtn(self, btn):
         if btn.text() == "Upper On":
            await self.mp.turn_on(0)
         if btn.text() =="Upper Off" :
            await self.mp.turn_off(0)
         if btn.text() == "Lower On":
            await self.mp.turn_on(1)
         if btn.text() == "Lower Off":
            await self.mp.turn_off(1)
         if btn.text() == "Schedule":
            await self.mp.sched_on(self.scheduler)
            self.scheduler.start()
            print(self.scheduler)
            print(self.scheduler.get_jobs())
                    
      def quit_app(self):
         print("quit_app")
         self.loop.stop()
         print("Loop running ", self.loop.is_running())
         self.loop.close()
         print("Loop closed ", self.loop.is_closed())
         self.close()
    
def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   loop = QEventLoop(app)
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   ex = Form(loop)
   ex.show()
   with loop:
      loop.run_forever()
        
   if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

When I run the code, it pops a Qt window with my upper/lower, on/off buttons. The buttons work fine and when pressed give me:

Tick! The time is: 2023-02-20 20:26:14.390022

The problem is the 'Schedule' button. I expect to receive the same output every 3 seconds but get the following:

TypeError: startTimer(self, int, timerType: Qt.TimerType = Qt.CoarseTimer): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'

Comment: Please provide a *valid* [mre]: 1. ensure that it's *both* minimal *and* reproducible (read the link above!); 2. since the cause of your issue is probably not caused by the usage of multiple files, merge the code in a single block, instead of using multiple files (which would force us to recreate the whole structure); 3. improve your imports, as there are lots of duplicates, comments and unnecessary imports; 4. it's unclear what is the purpose of the third snippet. Please, take your time to [edit] your question, rushing it will **not** help us, nor you.

Comment: I'm new to posting code for help so, hopefully I have done what you have  asked.

Comment: No, if you had I wouldn't have written the comment above. Please read that comment again and put your efforts in doing what has been requested.

Comment: Is that better? I edited my original, I think 8-)

Comment: It's a long story but I finally got it to work.

Comment: If you found a solution, you should share it with others by creating your own answer (using the related field, please read [answer]). Please note that your post is still not very good: that whole text block at its end is **completely unreadable**. Check how to properly [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and always check the post preview before submitting edits.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, my original question was concerning getting errors from AsyncioScheduler, specifically:

TypeError: startTimer(self, int, timerType: Qt.TimerType = Qt.CoarseTimer): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'

I was using the scheduler in a Qt application and not having much success. I finally got it to work and the modified code is as follows...

```
import sys
import asyncio
import qasync
from datetime import datetime
from asyncqt import asyncSlot
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

# Fake Kasa SmartStrip class.
# turn_on and turn_off are async functions, so use asyncio.sleep
# to implement
class SmartStrip:
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address
        
    async def update(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"update called at {datetime.now()}")
        
    async def turn_on(self, child):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"turn on child", child, "called at", datetime.now())

    async def turn_off(self, child):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"turn off child", child, "called at", datetime.now())

# Allow control (turn_on/turn_off) the individual sockets (upper/lower)
# in the wall plug
class MyPlug(SmartStrip):
    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        super().__init__(ip_address)
         
    async def turn_on_upper(self):
        await self.turn_on(0)
        
    async def turn_on_lower(self):
        await self.turn_on(1)
        
    async def turn_off_upper(self):
        await self.turn_off(0)
        
    async def turn_off_lower(self):
        await self.turn_off(1)
        
# The Qt goodies which contain buttons to (turn on/off)
# the (upper or lower) sockets. Also allows scheduling.
class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, loop=None):
       super(Form, self).__init__()
      
       self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
       asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
       self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler({'event_loop': self.loop}, timezone="America/New_York")

       layout = QVBoxLayout()
       self.setLayout(layout)
      
       # Initialize
       self.initialize = QPushButton("Initialize")
       self.initialize.clicked.connect(self.init_device)
       
       # Upper On
       self.up_on = QPushButton("Upper On")
       self.up_on.clicked.connect(self.turn_on_upper)

       # Upper Off
       self.up_off = QPushButton("Upper Off")
       self.up_off.clicked.connect(self.turn_off_upper)

       # Lower On
       self.lo_on = QPushButton("Lower On")
       self.lo_on.clicked.connect(self.turn_on_lower)

       # Lower Off
       self.lo_off = QPushButton("Lower Off")
       self.lo_off.clicked.connect(self.turn_off_lower)

       # Schedule
       self.sched = QPushButton("Schedule")
       self.sched.clicked.connect(self.schedule_mp)

       # Quit
       self.quit = QPushButton("Quit")
       self.quit.clicked.connect(self.quit_app)
      
       layout.addWidget(self.initialize)
       layout.addWidget(self.up_on)
       layout.addWidget(self.up_off)
       layout.addWidget(self.lo_on)
       layout.addWidget(self.lo_off)
       layout.addWidget(self.sched)
       layout.addWidget(self.quit)
      
       self.setWindowTitle("Outlet Demo")
       self.mp = MyPlug("10.0.0.31")
       
    # The following functions with the asyncSlot decorator
    # are called when a Qt button is clicked. Qt requires
    # the asyncSlot decorator
    @asyncSlot()
    async def init_device(self):
       print("Initialize device ************")
       await self.mp.update()
       print("******************************")

    @asyncSlot()
    async def turn_on_upper(self):
       print("turn_on_upper ****************")
       await self.mp.turn_on(0)
       print("******************************")
     
    @asyncSlot()
    async def turn_on_lower(self):
       print("turn_on_lower ****************")
       await self.mp.turn_on(1)
       print("******************************")
     
    @asyncSlot()
    async def turn_off_upper(self):
       print("turn_off_upper ***************")
       await self.mp.turn_off(0)
       print("******************************")
      
    @asyncSlot()
    async def turn_off_lower(self):
       print("turn_off_lower ***************")
       await self.mp.turn_off(1)
       print("******************************")
      
    # The following functions are submitted as jobs to
    # the scheduler. Same as the above functions but
    # without the asyncSlot decorator.
    async def sched_turn_on_upper(self):
        await self.turn_on_upper()

    async def sched_turn_on_lower(self):
       await self.turn_on_lower()
     
    async def sched_turn_off_upper(self):
       await self.turn_off_upper()
      
    async def sched_turn_off_lower(self):
       await self.turn_off_lower()

    def schedule_mp(self):
       # Turn on every 5 seconds
       self.scheduler.add_job(self.sched_turn_on_upper, 'interval', seconds=5)
       # Turn off every 7 seconds
       self.scheduler.add_job(self.sched_turn_off_upper, 'interval', seconds=7)
       print("*****")
       print("Scheduler jobs:\n", self.scheduler.print_jobs())
       print("*****")
       if not self.scheduler.running:
          self.scheduler.start()
      
    def quit_app(self):
       if self.scheduler.running:
          self.scheduler.shutdown()
       self.loop.stop()
       self.loop.close()
       self.close()


def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   
   # Since I'm running a Qt application, let's use a
   # QEventLoop
   loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   
   ex = Form(loop)
   ex.show()
   
   with loop:
      loop.run_forever()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```